# showModalBottomSheet and Border Radius

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a `showModalBottomSheet` with a container in Flutter. I want this container to have rounded top borders, but, when I tried this, there were a few small uncolored spaces in the corners. How can I delete them?

This is the code I used:

```
class OverlayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(...),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The result is the following:
[image]

I want to delete the white spaces at the top border.
Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reviewing the documentation, I realize that the `showModalBottomSheet<T>` function has a property called `backgroundColor` ‍♀️

Just adding:

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

to the `showModalBottomSheet` works.

*Thanks for the help anyway!*

Comment: You should mark your own answer as correct. To help other users.

Answer (score 1):

`ThemeData` has `bottomSheetTheme` parameter, you can override this as following :

```
MaterialApp(
        ...
        theme: ThemeData(
          ...
          bottomSheetTheme:
              BottomSheetThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
        ),
        ...
      ),
```

This will give `transparent` color for the `bottomSheet`

Comment: I used to create a parent ```Container``` and set it's color to something like ```Color(0xFF676767)``` to get this same result, thanks for this wonderful answer. OP, accept this answer.

Comment: My solution will apply the background color for all your bottom sheets, giving backgroundColor Property for each bottom sheets you created will make it harder later if you wanted to update the background color to another one. you can see even with the ThemeData i used ```backgroundColor``` same as you. @Jsancs

Comment: With your solution it will work for all BottomSheets in my app? Oh that's useful, thanks, I didn't understand it earlier XD

Comment: @Jsancs Yes all of them, and of course you can override the color if you want to any time using ```backgroundColor``` as you done before.